# How to calculate $\prod\limits_{p}\frac{p^2+1}{p^2-1}$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, products

When I input
$$
\prod _{p=2}^{\infty } \text{If}\left[\text{PrimeQ}[p],\frac{p^2+1}{p^2-1},1\right]
$$
in *Mathematica 12.0*, it gives out the value $1$.

[image]

The result is ridiculous, for that according to numerical evaluation we have
[image]

In fact, after some analysis we can find out the analytical result $\displaystyle  \prod_p \frac{1+p^{-s}}{1-p^{-s}}=\frac{\zeta(s)^2}{\zeta(2s)}$, so that $ \displaystyle \prod_p \frac{1+p^{-2}}{1-p^{-2}}=\frac{\zeta(2)^2}{\zeta(4)}=\frac{\left (\frac{\pi^2}{6}\right )^2}{\frac{\pi^4}{90}}=\frac{5}{2}$

I am wondering that if it is my fault (e.g. wrong input method) or a **bug** in *mathematica 12.0*.

Comment: it seems to have to do with the upper limit being $\infty$. Since doing something like `Product[If[PrimeQ[p], (p^2 + 1)/(p^2 - 1), 1], {p, 2, 100000}] // N` gives `2.5` which is the limit.  ps. it would be better to post your Mathematica code also in plain text to make it easier to copy and user. Eliminates mistakes.

Comment: Don't know why what you wrote doesn't work but the following does work:  `Product[(Prime[n]^2 + 1)/(Prime[n]^2 - 1), {n, 1, \[Infinity]}]`.

Comment: @JimB is it possible Mathematica knew about these special cases and just did a lookup for the result? Any other ones not in a lookup table, should not work if the upper limit is infinity, according to help?

Comment: @Nasser Good inference.  It does appear that the lower limit is recognized in whatever lookup is used as using `{n, 3, \[Infinity]}` also gives an appropriate answer.

Comment: Per Michael E2's comment/answer I'm not sure this is a bug, so I removed the tag. We try to be very careful about having only bugs confirmed by WRI or the community when using it.

Comment: Please don't use the [tag:bugs] tag when posting new questions. See the tag description for why.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A `Trace` reveals the problem:

```
Product[If[PrimeQ[p], (p^2 + 1)/(p^2 - 1), 1], {p, 2, 
   Infinity}] // Trace
(*
{Product[If[PrimeQ[p], (p^2 + 1)/(p^2 - 1), 1], {p, 2, Infinity}],
  {{PrimeQ[p],
    False},
   If[False, (p^2 + 1)/(p^2 - 1), 1],
   1},
  Product[1, {p, 2, Infinity}],
  1}
*)
```

The `If[]` statement is evaluated before the `Product`. In turn `PrimeQ[p]` is evaluated before `p` has any value, and it evaluates to `False` because the symbol `p` is not a prime integer.  Hence the product being evaluated is the product of an infinite number of ones.

*Update.*
The desired product can be computed with the following (just noticed that @JimB mentioned this [in a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200327/how-to-calculate-displaystyle-prod-p-fracp21p2-1/200331#comment518322_200327) around the time I was working on this answer):

```
Product[(Prime[p]^2 + 1)/(Prime[p]^2 - 1), {p, 1, Infinity}]
(*  5/2  *)
```

*Update 2.*

From the docs for [`Product`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Product.html):

> If a product cannot be carried out explicitly by multiplying a finite number of terms, `Product` will attempt to find a symbolic result. In this case, `f` is first evaluated symbolically.

As @Sjoerd mentions in a [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/43522/sjoerd-smit), this problem with `PrimeQ` is explicitly pointed out in the documentation for [`Sum`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html)

Comment: Oh, then it seems that this is definitely a bug in *mathematica*.

Comment: @FFjet I don't think it's a bug. Most functions ending in `Q` evaluate to `True` or `False` no matter whether the input is numeric or not.  Sometimes it's irritating, but it is by design and therefore not a bug, imo.  `Product` has to inspect its arguments to know what to do. When it evaluates the first one, it evaluates to `1` (because `PrimeQ[p]` is `False`). You can try `If[Element[p, Primes], (p^2 + 1)/(p^2 - 1), 1]`, which does not evaluate until `p` has a numeric value.  However, `Product` does not handle this form, but `NProduct` will produce a somewhat poor approximation.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Agreed. The documentation for `Sum` explicitly lists this problem in the "Possible Issues" section.

Comment: ok, i see, thx :D